# Как создать картинку для css и html отображения

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, photoshop

Кто может определить в какой программе была сделана картинка и как мне добиться того же со своими картинками, желательно в онлайн редакторах, а не фотошоп программе установленной на компьютере, т.к. ее у меня нет. Пытался делать через онлайн сервис [photoshop-online](http://pixelonline.ru/photoshop-online), вроде бы все хорошо, но при вставке в `html` и `css` она не отображается вообще.

Изображение оригинала картинки "нажмите что бы увеличить ее":

[image: картинка]

На картинке видно что она черного цвета и ее дубликат отображается снизу белого цвета. Так же по свойствам размеры ее `12х24`. Отображается белая часть в `html`, черная видимо как то скрывается в `css`.

Изображение не оригинальной картинки "мои неудачные попытки":

[image: картинка2]

Именно моя не оригинальная версия картинки не отображается при вставке в `html` и `css`.

Вот часть кода `css`:

```
.social-icon
{
max-width:100px;
height:24px;
line-height:24px;
display:block;
position:relative;
padding:0 10px 0 42px;
margin:0 0 8px 0;
font-size:12px;
color:#fff;
font-family:'Ubuntu';
text-decoration:none;
background:#595959;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 -4px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 -4px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
box-shadow:inset 0 -4px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

-webkit-border-radius:2px;
-moz-border-radius:2px;
border-radius:2px;

-webkit-transition:all 0.3s;
-moz-transition:all 0.3s;
transition:all 0.3s;
}

.social-icon span
{
position:absolute;
top:6px;
left:9px;
width:12px;
height:12px;

-webkit-transition:all 0.3s;
-moz-transition:all 0.3s;
transition:all 0.3s;
}

.social-icon:after
{
content:'';
position:absolute;
left:30px;
top:0;
bottom:0;
width:1px;
background:#fff;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.30);
-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
box-shadow:-1px 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

Когда меняю высоту `height:12px;` в `.social-icon span` на `24px` отображается как положено не оригинальная картинка, но после этого оригинальная картинка показывается на всю свою высоту, т.е. на `24px` и верхняя часть черного цвета отображения тоже видна. Как быть?

Comment: Должно все отображаться, видимо вы что-то не так делаете. "Особых картинок" для веба не существует (на сколько я знаю (есть особенности, но они не должны влиять на отображение как таковое)).

Comment: @MedvedevDev возможно, но меняя эти две картинки поочереди, только одна из них отображается оригинальная. Что это мистика? Не понимаю почему так.

Comment: смотрите в панель разработчика, подключается ли картинка в принципе или выдает ошибку (может пути неправильно указываете). Тут же она отображается.

Comment: @MedvedevDev с путями все корректно 100%. Взгляните пожалуйста на `css` код, который добавил в своем начальном вопросе. Может быть вы поймете в чем тут дело?

Comment: Преоброзуйте файл в вектор, с помощью `adobe illustrator` и сохраните в формате `svg`. Потом используете это.

Comment: @StackOverflow `adobe illustrator` он платный, посоветуйте лучше онлайн редактор.

Comment: `image to vector converter` напишите в `google`, но они часто очень искажают изображения, и для маленьких иконок это будет видно очень плохо

Comment: @StackOverflow хорошо спасибо, попробую.

Comment: @StackOverflow это не то что мне нужно было, но все равно спасибо за участие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С вашим кодом `css` все в порядке, у вас не показывается не оригинальная картинка потому, что на самой картинке нет отражения нижней части белого цвета.

Comment: да вы правы, даже и не заметил этого, спасибо!